# Every group has a presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

My question is pretty simple: prove that every group has a presentation. This is always assumed when I read about presentations but no one has actually proved this (as far is I can search the internet). It seems very logical to me that this is true.
I've tried saying that if $G$ is a group, then $\langle G\mid\phantom{G} \rangle$ is a presentation for it, but I'm not sure wether this is true.

Comment: Apparently, you did not search really well...https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group. Although wikipedia is not always reliable, the section 'Some theorems' contains an outline of proof which you can easily verify yourself :)

Comment: Hint: They didn't say every group has a _finite_ presentation...

Comment: A little stronger: every group admits a presentation over any generating family (as prove in Federico's answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every group $G$ has a presentation, yes, since $G$ is spanned by $G$ and by all relations $g.h=gh$, with $g,h\in G$.

Comment: So the actually _presentation_ would include every $abc^{-1}$, for every $a,b,c$ with $ab=c$, right?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Right. That's how I should have put it.

Comment: Even safer to consider the generators $e_g$ for $g\in G$ and mod out by the relators $e_ge_he_{gh}^{-1}$ for all $g,h$, to avoid confusion between computing in the group and in the free group on the family $(e_g)_{g\in G}$.

Answer (score 4):

We can consider  $A\subset G$ a set of generators of $G$ (that could be $G$). Now there is always a free group of words in  $A$ that I called $FA$.

By the inclusion map $i: A\to G$ you can apply the universal property of free groups to get an homomorphism $\phi: FA\to G$. This map is surjective because for construction $A$ is a set of generators of $G$ and so, by first homomorphism theorem, you have that

$G\cong \frac{FA}{\ker (\phi)}$

And so a presentation of $G$ is $\langle A \mid \ker(\phi)\rangle$

Comment: Starting with "*one of the sets of generators of G*" makes no sense since you are currently in the process of proving that there *is* such a set.

Comment: I’m saying that if A is a set of generators of G then it is possibile to construct a presentation of G in function of A. In general there is always a set of generators of G, that is G, so there is always a presentation of G

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, but as it was written it made no sense. Starting with $G$ is the only way.

Comment: Now could be correct?

Comment: No, the last sentence is blatantly wrong.

Comment: No it sounds correct to me: for every generating subset (actually generating family, which allows non-injective family) one gets a presentation, and one choice of generating family is the identity map $G\to G$.